# Displaying Tumblr Posts in a Specified Order

Tags: blogs, tumblr

What I would like to accomplish is a Tumblr blog whose main page ('home/index') displays posts in an order specified by the blog owner (in this case, myself; I do not want it to display the most recent first, nor do I want it to display in chronological order.

The ideal would be to tag or otherwise specify a post with a number (e.g. '1', '2') and regardless of which was posted first, 2 is displayed after 1 if I designate it as so (except a bit more complex than that, because I was hoping to use dates).

Is this possible? And if so, how would I go about doing it?

edit: (To more clearly illustrate the purpose for this, I'm hoping to display posts containing content that is supposed to be in 'chronological order'. However, the posts themselves cannot be displayed chronologically because the content I'm putting in the posts is not all known; if I discover new content, I need to insert it into a pre-existing timeline).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to post your post and then edit the date to be in between the two posts you want it to be.

Another solution would be to use [tumbr's API v1](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1) with JSON. You would make a function that first calls something like `http://yoururl.tumblr.com/api/read/json?tagged=1` where 1 is actually a variable and from there, if it returns a post, then you increment your variable and call the function again and it will repeat for as many number tags as you have.